# does rspec when using rails use inflection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am reading through the [michael hartl tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top); with a model user that has a method "follow"; One of the tests has an assertion like "should_not be_following"
so I assume inflection is used here internally to find the follow method?

Comment: Sure it wasn't `should_not be_following`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, [it's using RSpec's own rule around predicate methods](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-11/docs/built-in-matchers/predicate-matchers):

```
thing.should_not be_following
```

is just shorthand for

```
thing.following?.should_not be(true)
```

Comment: just saw there is a "following" method in the user model...thanks for this answer though..doesnt hurt to know..